# Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the 'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have 2 projects ones call **Api** which is a library for my DbContext and other call **AdminPanel** which is an Asp.NetCore project for my website.
in The Api Project my Dbcontext inherit `IdentityDbContext<AppUser>` and the 
***Appuser*** class is in the same project in model folder which inherited from IdentityUser class.
Now in my **AdminPanel** in Startup.cs i use

```
         services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
                    {
                        config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                        config.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                    })
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
 services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<ApplicationUser>, AppClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
            services.AddScoped<SignInManager<ApplicationUser>, AuditableSignInManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

which ApplicationUser is a class in **AdminPanel** now when i run AdminPanel project i'll get

> An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to
>   process this request. Please review the following specific error
>   details and modify your source code appropriately.
>           Generated Code
>           One or more compilation references are missing. Ensure that your project is referencing 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' and the
>   'PreserveCompilationContext' property is not set to false.
>            The type or namespace name 'ApplicationUser' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't know what should i do.
beforehand Sorry about my English. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using `ApplicationUser` in any of your views?

Comment: yes in my _login.chtml

Comment: Try referring to it with a fully qualified namespace, to see if that works.